# SUM function returning 0 value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, function-keys

DATA SET PREVIEW

I Used the sum function to calculate the time, as the trip duration is in seconds i used =SUM(cell/60) and then convert them to HH:MM:SS, but some of the cells are returning 00:00:00
check the two screenshots for better understanding
1 [Data with function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMBAC.jpg)
2 [data returning 0 value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjKz0.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your durations are in seconds, you must divide them 86400 to get the correct results not by 60.
Thus, all your results are wrong. For example, 31117 seconds = 08:39:37 not 14:48. Plus, you don't need to use the `SUM` function as you are not adding/summing.